# WebDriver python NoSuchElementException with explicit tag name in xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

In my selenium test the following code:

```
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='myid']")
print el.tag_name
```

outputs as expected

```
ul
```

However, if `//*` wildcard is replaced with explicit `//ul` in the XPath expression:

```
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@id='myid']")
```

`NoSuchElementException` is thrown. Can't explain it. Using css selector:

```
el = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ul#myid")
```

works fine.

Using: Windows 7 x64, python 2.7 x64, selenium 2.39, FireFox 26.0

Comment: Can you provide the URL that you are passing to driver.get?

Comment: It's localhost, own application. Can't provide the full xhtml, but the element is present, I can see it in the inspector, and xhtml is valid.

Comment: Are you sure that both cases are consistent (//* always works, //ul always fails)?

Comment: So far yes, but I keep investigating it. Looks like the timing issue - with wildcard and CSS it becomes unstable with more complicated expression.

Comment: I would expect //* to take longer than //ul... So perhaps the element you are looking for is created after the page is loaded (with javascript), and not "ready on time"...

Comment: That is true, but it fails even with multiple attempts and when implicitly_wait is set to several seconds. Inspector shows desired element in the tree by the time attempts are made.

Comment: Could it be that the `ul` element is in the XHTML namespace, and that's why `//ul` fails to match it?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's the XHTML namespace. See similar questions [here](http://www.seleniumwebdriver.com/google-selenium-webdriver/find_elements-by-xpath-for-xhtml-pages/) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-developers/U6A5FktzLMQ).
My impression is that it's a limitation of Webdriver/Selenium that there's not a way to declare namespaces for XPath to use, and that problem has not been resolved.

So you may be stuck with a workaround, such as `//*...` or `//*[local-name() = 'ul']`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using Xpath is very inaccurate when using selenium. It is even frowned upon directly in the selenium documentation. Use the ID or Name unless they are dynamic or you have some other reason you cannot use them.